# How to extract a sublist from a list where the last character of the previous element is the same as the first character of the last element? - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim of this program is to take a list of words and print the longest possible 'chain' of the words, the conditions of which are that each word has the same first character as the last character of the word before it.

The example I used to test this program is the list of animals:

```
giraffe
elephant
ant
tiger
raccoon
cat
hedgehog
mouse
```

The longest chain should read:

```
hedgehog
giraffe
elephant
tiger
raccoon
```

However when I run the program below it returns:

```
giraffe
elephant
tiger
raccoon
```

Please could someone help to identify the tiny issue with my program that might be causing this. It's probably obvious but I'm fresh out of ideas.

Here is the program:

```
from random import *


def legal_chain(word, chain):
    """Tests if a word can be 'legally' added to the end
of a chain"""
if word[0] == chain[-1][-1]:
        return True
else: 
    return False

def longest_chain(chain, V, longest):
 """ Returns the longest possible chain of strings where the
 starting character of each string is the same as the last
character from a given starting word and vocabulary V"""

 extended = False
 for word in V:
        if legal_chain(word, chain) is True:
        V.remove(word)
        chain.append(word)
        longest = longest_chain(chain, V, longest)
        extended = True
 if extended is False:
        if len(chain) > len(longest):
        longest = chain

 return longest

def find_longest(chain, V, longest):
    """Finds the longest chain for all possible starting words
   within a given vocabulary V"""
    longs = []
    i = 0
    for word in V:
        chain = [word]
        longer = longest_chain(chain, V, longest)
        longs.append(longer)
    if len(longs) == len(V):
    while len(longs) > 1:
        if len(longs[i]) < len(longs[i + 1]):
            del longs[i]
        elif len(longs[i]) > len(longs[i + 1]):
            del longs[i + 1]
        else:
            i += 1
    return longs

def print_longest(chain, V, longest):
    """Displays the longest chain of words with each word on a new line"""
    the_longest = find_longest(chain, V, longest)
    for list in the_longest:
        for word in list:
            print(word, '\n')




v = open('animals.txt', 'r').readlines()
V = [word.strip() for word in v]
longest = []
chain = []
print_longest(chain, V, longest)
```

PLEASE IGNORE ANY INDENTATION ERRORS, THE PROGRAM WORKS WITHOUT AN ERROR, THERE IS AN ISSUE WITH COPY AND PASTE!

**edit** I believe the following fixes the indentation errors (in the sense of no compiler errors, and output is the same as OP had stated):

```
from random import *


def legal_chain(word, chain):
  """Tests if a word can be 'legally' added to the end of a chain"""
  if word[0] == chain[-1][-1]:
    return True
  else:
    return False

def longest_chain(chain, V, longest):
 """ Returns the longest possible chain of strings where the
 starting character of each string is the same as the last
 character from a given starting word and vocabulary V"""

 extended = False
 for word in V:
    if legal_chain(word, chain) is True:
        V.remove(word)
        chain.append(word)
        longest = longest_chain(chain, V, longest)
        extended = True
    if extended is False:
        if len(chain) > len(longest):
          longest = chain

 return longest

def find_longest(chain, V, longest):
  """Finds the longest chain for all possible starting words
  within a given vocabulary V"""
  longs = []
  i = 0
  for word in V:
    chain = [word]
    longer = longest_chain(chain, V, longest)
    longs.append(longer)
    if len(longs) == len(V):
      while len(longs) > 1:
        if len(longs[i]) < len(longs[i + 1]):
            del longs[i]
        elif len(longs[i]) > len(longs[i + 1]):
          del longs[i + 1]
        else:
                i += 1
  return longs

def print_longest(chain, V, longest):
  """Displays the longest chain of words with each word on a new line"""
  the_longest = find_longest(chain, V, longest)
  for list in the_longest:
    for word in list:
        print(word, '\n')

v = open('animals.txt', 'r').readlines()
V = [word.strip() for word in v]
longest = []
chain = []
print_longest(chain, V, longest)
```

Comment: Before addressing issues with your code itself, you need to make your indentation consistent.  You seem to be mixing tabs and spaces (run your code using `python -tt yourcodename.py` to confirm).

Comment: BTW, `chain` have a sort of different meaning in `python`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

Comment: @DSM indentations were merely a copy and paste screw up

Comment: @harryjmm - still, if you could fix the indentation we can run your code and help debug. Right now it won't run when copy/pasted into my editor.

Comment: @harryjmm: that's hard to believe.  I'm looking at your raw paste right now, and you mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: @DSM if you can tell me how to give/show you the original file, I can show you there should be no issue with indentations.

Comment: @harryjmm - I have "fixed" (to the best of my ability, and with some guessing) your indentation. Please check this is still the same code.

Comment: @Floris thank you, sorry, bit new to the Stack Overflow thing...

Comment: i'm pretty sure a short recursive function can solve the problem, instead of using this long-winded loops

Comment: I think you need to test every possible permutation of the names to see if it's legal, and how long it is. As it is, you try to add words in the order in which they are in the list… thus you miss a number of permutations (like the one starting `hedgehog`…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
words_array = ['giraffe', 'elephant', 'ant', 'tiger', 'racoon', 'cat', 'hedgedog', 'mouse']

def longest_chain(words_array, current_chain):

    res_chain = list(current_chain)
    test_chain = []

    for s in words_array:
        temp_words_array = list(words_array)
        temp_words_array.remove(s)

        if len(current_chain) == 0:
            test_chain = longest_chain(temp_words_array, current_chain + [s])
        else:
            if s[0] == current_chain[-1][-1]:
                test_chain = longest_chain(temp_words_array, current_chain + [s])

        if len(test_chain) > len(res_chain):
            res_chain = list(test_chain)

    return res_chain


print(longest_chain(words_array, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your list is small:

```
from itertools import permutations, chain

animals = """giraffe
elephant
ant
tiger
raccoon
cat
hedgehog
mouse"""


longest = sorted([[(j,k) for j, k in zip(i[:-1],i[1:]) if j[-1] == k[0]] \
for i in permutations([i for i in animals.split('\n')])], key=len)[-1]

print list(chain(*[longest[0], [i[1] for i in longest]]))
```

**[out]:**

```
['hedgehog', 'giraffe', 'giraffe', 'elephant', 'tiger', 'raccoon']
```

**NOTE:** The list comprehension to get the `longest` chain is the same as such a nested loop:

```
animals = animals.split('\n')
animal_chains = []
# Loop through all possible permutations of the list.
for i in permutations(animals): 
    possible_chain = []
    # Reading two items at once in a list.
    for j, k in zip(i[:-1], i[1:]): 
        # Check if last character of the this animal == first character of the next.
        if j[-1] == k[0]:
            possible_chain.append((j,k))
    animal_chains.append(possible_chain)

# sort the animal_chains by length and get the longest.
longest = sorted(animal_chains, key=len)[-1]
```